# How to write mixed derivative of space and time in PINN Solvers

Tags: neural-network, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the equation given below. But I am struggling to write the time derivative operator to the space derivative (i.e., the third term in the equation) PINN Solvers

[image: Non-linear time dependent ODE]

Comment: Your question would benefit a bit more from context: The source of this equation, the meaning of the variables (e.g. `w` is often angular freq, `r` and beta have many possible meanings), and your current approach to the problem. There are many numerical derivation techniques, it'd be better to help you with the way you're currently trying.